# Проблема отображения InfoMessage в Ado.net

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Я создал `SqlConnection`, подписался под `connection.InfoMessage` и запустил команду в другом потоке.

К примеру, при восстановлении базы из bak-файла он отписывает прогресс 0% - 100% etc в Management Studio, но в моей реализации только после окончания выводит полный пакет сообщений. Пробовал даже воспользоваться `BeginExecuteNonQuery()`, но и это не помогло.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы Print сообщения отписывались мгновенно, а не после окончания операции.

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось намного проще.

`sqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;`

дает нужный результат.